# Prevent from deleting a UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I'm making an app where you jump between two Views and I don't want two generate them new every time I show one of them. So I stored ViewA as a reference in `ViewB`, that I can present `ViewA` later again.

In ViewA in the prepare func
`viewB.root = self`

Now, when I try to access the ViewA, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error`. I figured out that this is because the ViewA unloads and gets deleted, so my reference is like nil.

Any1 has a suggestion?

Comment: how you navigating your app from one to another viewCont ?

Comment: Paste your code. How you are creating viewB?

Answer (score 0):

Use segue instead of using references of one controller in another.

Study this link and you will know more about navigating between different View controllers.

[Navigation controller and Segue](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462)

Answer (score 0):

You can cache viewController

```
let cache = NSCache()
// get your viewController from cache  
let controller = cache.objectForKey(object) as? YourViewController
// store viewController into cache  
cache.setObject(controller, forKey: object)
```